# Setting base url with AngularJs not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using $http.get with a relative url like this:

```
 $http.get('/api/product')
                .then(function (res) { });
```

The resultant call is:

```
GET http://localhost/api/product 404 (Not Found)
```

Now the problem is my site is running in IIS under a virtual directory, the structure is like this:

```
Sites
    - Default Web Site
        - Website (Virtual Directory)
        - Services (Virtual Directory)
```

So the URL I actually want AngularJs to call is:

```
GET http://localhost/website/api/product
```

I have tried setting the BASE element like this:

```
<base href="Website/">
```

(And using `http://localhost/website/`)

But nothing seems to correct the URL?

What can I do? I would still like to use the relative URL with angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
$http.get('/api/product').then(function (res) { });
```

to

```
$http.get('/website/api/product').then(function (res) { });
```

Comment: Can you provide more explanation?

Comment: Change from $http.get('/api/product').then(function (res) { }); to  $http.get('/website/api/product').then(function (res) { });

Comment: To score points, it helps if you update the answer with that comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `$http.get('api/product')
                .then(function (res) { });`